# How do I save data explorer queries?

Tags: support, data-explorer

Just found the data explorer, it's a lot of fun.

How do I save* queries?

My workaround:

1. experiment a bunch, after 20 revisions settle on something I like
2. go to my history, find the query
3. favorite it

Just wondering if that's the accepted way to do it, or if there's an easier/better way.

---

*Note: it seems like all queries are saved in my history.  I want to keep the *good* ones in a special group!

Comment: Would it be more helpful if you were able to filter your favourited queries to only show ones that you owned?

Comment: Yes, it definitely would!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The "edited" tab of your Data Explorer profile will show you all queries you've worked on grouped within their revision set, so that each entry on that page is a "distinct" query (of which there may be many revisions).

If you have some queries you aren't interested in, this list isn't necessarily ideal, since the queries you want to save can be buried underneath other ones. In that case, favouriting the query is currently the best way to go, although I admit that not being able to do so from the edit screen is rather annoying (you can click-thru the permalink, though).

I suppose it would be possible to have a view where you could see select queries that you've created through some kind of explicit hide/show option, but I'm not sure if there's any benefit to that so long as the favouriting process from the edit page is improved.

Answer (score 9):

Compose a new query and run it.  A link will appear below the query box with the title **permalink**.  Click the permalink hyperlink and  after the page loads click the star in the upper left to save it as a favorite.

Comment: ridiculous. anything wrong with the way a billion other pages handle saving, with a "save" button?

Comment: easiest way.Thanks a lot :)